# Merge Contacts throw an error: DB Error: no such table

Tags: wordpress, contacts

Enabling the debug mode, I got more details:

> Error Field   Error Value Type    DB_Error Code   -18 Message DB Error: no
> such table Mode   16 UserInfo UPDATE civicrm_afform_submission SET
> contact_id = 123 WHERE contact_id = 456 [nativecode=1146 ** Table
> 'wordpress.civicrm_afform_submission' doesn't exist] DebugInfo    UPDATE
> civicrm_afform_submission SET contact_id = 123 WHERE contact_id = 456
> [nativecode=1146 ** Table 'wordpress.civicrm_afform_submission'
> doesn't exist]

It looks like this table is created by the Form Builder extension. I tried to enable it but the table is still not created.

Answer (score 2):

Can you uninstall the extension and re-install?

i.e Disable >> Uninstall >> Install

Or you can run below query

```
CREATE TABLE `civicrm_afform_submission` (
  `id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Unique Submission ID',
  `contact_id` int unsigned,
  `afform_name` varchar(255) COMMENT 'Name of submitted afform',
  `data` text COMMENT 'IDs of saved entities',
  `submission_date` timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `status_id` int unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 1 COMMENT 'fk to Afform Submission Status options in civicrm_option_values',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT FK_civicrm_afform_submission_contact_id FOREIGN KEY (`contact_id`) REFERENCES `civicrm_contact`(`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL
)
ENGINE=InnoDB ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;
```

Comment: Thanks! Reinstalling the extension didn't work. I had to create the table manually. But why this extension is required for merge action? And if it's required, why it's not activated by default?

Comment: Ah, the problem only happens when the Form Core ext is activated and the Form Builder not.